# How to create a Field dependency between Case Status to Case Type in Salesforce

Tags: field-dependencies

we have a Two Standard Fields in Case Object like Status(picklist) and Type(Picklist).
When i click the Status is closed, That related Type Picklist Field Need to Dependent.

How to Solve this issue. in my org.
Please help on that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard picklist fields can be controlling fields but not dependent fields.

Kindly review [Idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kovQAAQ) link and vote for this feature and check dependent picklist considerations [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_dependent_field_considerations.htm&type=5).

Thanks,